# Rails: Using Ruby threads to run background jobs in Rails 4 applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, passenger, puma

I am running a Rails web application under Phusion Passenger (version 5.0.7). Some http requests trigger workflows that are run as background jobs in a thread-pool (using Concurrent Ruby futures). Given that Phusion Passenger is a forking server, I now realize that there is no guarantee that the worker process will not be shutdown once there are no pending requests being serviced. This could simply abort whatever background processing that could be running in some thread-pool in that process.

Is there a way to make this work on Phusion Passenger? Alternatively, will Puma be a better choice for such a use case?

Comment: Why not use a separate process for background stuff?

Comment: Could you please add an answer on how to go about doing that? The reason I asked the question. I am not keen on Delayed Jobs, Sidekiq, etc. because I already have working code that deals with the workflows adequately well.

Comment: Does your code also handle server restart (does it lose jobs)?

Comment: Yes. It does a pretty good job of handling server restarts, using the application model to store job contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the HTTP server to run a background job. Check out Rails' [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) facilities for managing a job queue and processing them.

Comment: Can I use a custom implementation instead of a Sidekiq, Resque, etc? I have a large amount of well-tested code which currently handles the background processing.

Comment: Well, you could of course implement the API by changing one of the existing backend implementations (i. e. https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). You can also just run a rails tasks fro your code on the console with http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner